# How to combine 2 images to form hybrid image?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, imagej

I am implementing hybrid image with ImageJ and stuck at merging low filter image and high filter image to form a hybrid image.

This is what I already done.I have 2 images from Gaussian Blur and Laplician of Gaussian filer. I need to merge these 2 images by layer after that. Any idea how to achieve it?

```
import ij.*;
import ij.process.*;
import ij.gui.*;
import java.awt.*;
import ij.plugin.filter.*;
import ij.plugin.*;
import ij.io.*;
import java.io.*;


public class HybridImage_Plugin implements PlugInFilter{    
int cfsize=3;   
String img_lowPass;
String img_highPass;
private double[][] filter;
private double sigma;
 float w=2 ,delta=0 , thr=0;
    int mode=0;

//dialogbox
private boolean GUI()
{
    GenericDialog gd = new GenericDialog("Enter Values", IJ.getInstance());             
    gd.addNumericField("Sigma (3,5,9,17,35)", cfsize, 0);       
    gd.addStringField("Low-Pass", "/home/atrx/ImageJ/plugins/hybridimage/l1.tif");
    gd.addStringField("High-Pass", "/home/atrx/ImageJ/plugins/hybridimage/l2.tif");
    return getUserParams(gd);
}

//get parameters    
private boolean getUserParams(GenericDialog gd)
{   
    gd.showDialog();        
    if (gd.wasCanceled())
    {
        return false;
    }           
    cfsize = (int) gd.getNextNumber();
    img_lowPass = gd.getNextString();       
    img_highPass= gd.getNextString();                   
    return true;
}   

public int setup(String arg, ImagePlus imp) {
      return PlugInFilter.NO_IMAGE_REQUIRED;
}

public void run(ImageProcessor ip) {
    int[][] result;
    if(GUI() == false)
    {
        return;
    }   
    else
    {           
        Opener opener1 = new Opener();
        Opener opener2 = new Opener();
        ImagePlus imp1= opener1.openImage(img_lowPass);
        ImagePlus imp2= opener2.openImage(img_highPass);
        //imp1.show("Low Pass Image");
        //imp2.show("HighPass Image");          
        ImageProcessor ip1 = imp1.getProcessor();
        ImageProcessor ip2 = imp2.getProcessor();

        //lowpass filter(Gaussian Blur)
        ip1.blurGaussian(cfsize);
        showProcessor(ip1,"Low Pass Filtered Image");

        //highpass filter(LoG)
        int csize = ip2.getHeight();
        int rsize = ip2.getWidth();
        Rectangle rect = ip2.getRoi();
        int d0,a0,acr,dow,it;
            int  i,x,y;
            double h12, h21, ft, h1h2, h2h1, fmu, dh, dv;
        double r, dt, dmx, dmn;
        float logaus[] = new float[(rect.width>rect.height)? rect.width : rect.height];
        float   gaus[] = new float[(rect.width>rect.height)? rect.width : rect.height];
        float  dgaus[] = new float[(rect.width>rect.height)? rect.width : rect.height];
        long zcn =0;
        byte pixels[] = (byte[])ip2.getPixels();
        int img_in[]  = new int[rect.width*rect.height];
            if (cfsize<0) cfsize=3;
            if (cfsize>35) cfsize=35;
        if(w<0) w=0;
        int fsize = (int)(cfsize*w);
        if (fsize%2 == 0)
        {
            fsize += 1;
        }
        double dimg[] = new double[rect.height*rect.width];
        double dr[] = new double[rect.height*rect.width];

        i=0;

        for(y=rect.y;y<(rect.y+rect.height);y++)
        {
            for(x=rect.x;x<(rect.x+rect.width);x++)
            {
                img_in[i] = (pixels[(y*rsize)+x]&0xff);
                i++;
            }
            }
        int size = rect.width + fsize -1;
        int image[] = new int[(rect.width+fsize-1)*(rect.height+fsize-1)];
        int extension= (fsize/2);
            for( i=0; i<rect.height;i++)
        {
            System.arraycopy(img_in,(i*rect.width),image,( ((i+extension)*(rect.width+fsize-1))+ extension ),rect.width);
        }

            h1h2= h2h1 = h12 =0.0;

            for(i=1; i<( (fsize+1) /2);i++)
        {
            w = (float)cfsize/(float)2.0/(float)1.414;
            ft = i/w;               
            gaus[i] = (float)Math.exp(-ft*ft/2);
            h1h2 += 2.0 *(gaus[i]);
            logaus[i] =(float)(1-ft*ft)*(float)Math.exp(-ft*ft/2);
            h2h1 += 2.0*(logaus[i]);
            dgaus[i] =(float)ft*(float)Math.exp(-ft*ft/2);
            }
        fmu = (h2h1 + 1)* (h1h2+1);         

        int prel[] = new int[rect.width+1];
        dmx = -99999.9;
        dmn =  99999.9;

        int limit = ((rect.width+fsize-1)*(rect.height+fsize-1));
            for(d0=0;d0<rect.height;d0++)
        {
            for(a0=0;a0<rect.width;a0++)
            {

                acr = a0 + fsize/2;
                dow = d0 + fsize/2;
                dh = dv = 0.0;
                h1h2 = h2h1 = 0.0;
                for (int j=1; j<(fsize+1)/2; j++)
                {
                    int a0d0, a0d1, a1d0, a1d1;
                    h12=h21=0.0;

                    for(i=1;i<(fsize+1)/2;i++)
                    {
                        a0d0 = acr-i+((dow-j)*size);
                        a0d1 = acr-i+((dow+j)*size);
                        a1d0 = acr+i+((dow-j)*size);
                        a1d1 = acr+i+((dow+j)*size);

                        h12 += logaus[i]*(image[a0d0] + image[a0d1]+
                                    image[a1d0] + image[a1d1]);
                        h21 += gaus[i]*  (image[a0d0] + image[a0d1] +
                                    image[a1d0] + image[a1d1]);
                        }
                    a0d0 = acr-j+dow*size;
                    a0d1 = acr+(dow-j)*size;
                    a1d0 = acr+j+dow*size;
                    a1d1 = acr+(dow+j)*size;

                    h1h2 += gaus[j] * (h12+ image[a0d0]+image[a0d1]+
                                image[a1d0]+image[a1d1]);
                    h2h1 += logaus[j]*(h21+ image[a0d0]+ image[a0d1] +
                                image[a1d0] + image[a1d1] );

                    if(thr != 0.0)
                    {
                        dh += dgaus[j] * ( image[a1d0] - image[a0d0] );
                        dv += dgaus[j] * ( image[a1d1] - image[a0d1] );
                    }
                }
                dt = dimg[d0*rect.width+a0] = h1h2 + h2h1 + (2*image[dow*size+acr]) ;
                if (dt > dmx) dmx = dt;
                if (dt < dmn) dmn = dt;
                if( thr!= 0.0)
                {
                    dr[(d0*rect.width)+a0] = Math.abs(dh) + Math.abs(dv);
                }
            }
        }
        dmx = (dmx-dmn) / 2;
        dmn += dmx;
        int row=0, column=0;
        for(d0=0;d0<rect.height;d0++)
        {
            for(a0=0;a0<rect.width;a0++)
            {
                int id = (d0*rect.width) +a0;
                int index = rsize*(rect.y+d0) + (a0+rect.x);                    
                int k = 15;                 
                    it = (int)(dt = (dimg[id] - (dmn-delta*dmx))*255 / (dmx*(1+Math.abs(delta))));                             
                                switch(mode){
                    case 0:
                        pixels[index] = (byte)((dt-dmn+dmx)/dmx*127);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        pixels[index] = (byte)Math.abs(it);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        pixels[index] = (byte)( ((dt!=0)?((dt>0) ? 1: -1) : 0) * 192);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                    default:
                        r = dr[id];
                        it = ( (dt!=0) ? ((dt>0) ? 1: -1) : 0);
                        if( it==0 && r>=thr)
                        {
                            k = 255;
                                    zcn++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if( (it*prel[a0]<0 || it*prel[a0+1]<0) && r>=thr)
                            {
                                k = 255;
                                zcn++;
                            }
                        }
                        prel[a0+1] = it;
                        if(k==255 || mode!=3)
                        pixels[index] = (byte)k;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        showProcessor(ip2,"High Pass Filtered Image");          
    }

}

static void showProcessor(ImageProcessor ip, String title){
    ImagePlus win = new ImagePlus(title,ip);
    win.show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried performing a weighted sum?

```
OUT = w*LPF + (1 - w)*HPF
```

This kind of sum is used everywhere.  In particular, image blending, alpha matting and even in some optimization schemes.

However because there are patches of varying spatial frequencies all around your image, you may have to make the weight adaptive.  You also have to choose which one you want to emphasize more.  Do you want the low pass or high pass information to stand out more?  Depending on which you want, you might want to use information in either one of those images and run it through some distance or similarity measure to get the right weight.

Comment: thanks man! it shows me the way to do it. I think I can blend pixels from each images with certain weight like you point it out.

Comment: You're very welcome.  To start off with something simple, try a constant weight (i.e. `w = 0.4`) and see what the results are like.  You may end up with something acceptable and you won't have to do any more work than you have to!